# PHP Sort multidimensional array where key is a number?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have some multidimensional arrays like this (I trimmed sub-array values in this example):

```
Array (     
  [name] => This is my array name,
  [0] => Array ( [id] => 9, [multiply] => 2, [name] => Item name ),
  [1] => Array ( [id] => 24, [multiply] => 1, [name] => Another name, 
                    [sub-array] => Array(has more data here..)
              )
)
```

I'd like to **sort only the numbered keys** by the [multiply] field DESCENDING, **the [name] array needs to stay at the beginning**.

I've tried using usort(), but I need the [name] key to stay as it is.

Any hint what php-function could help me sort my multidimensional arrays?

Comment: You can use recursive function along with `array_map()` for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up using the similar function array_walk() instead